# C# single instance class used by multiple EXEs

Tags: c#, .net, dll, singleton

I have a class that acts as a 'zoneManager', it keeps track of which physical spaces are occupied by moving parts in a machine(robot arms/doors/etc..). Its a separate project that will be added in as a 'plug-and-play' DLL, I'm just unsure, given lack of Singleton experience if:

1. I have setup this code in a way to function as a single instance
2. How do I utilize it in exe/call to the functions? I don't just add as a reference the DLL and create/instantiate an instance like normal right? I feel like that defeats singleton somehow, or am I overthinking?
3. this class' Functions will be called from a 3rd party program on a different PC over WCF, so I'll need to ensure everyone is talking to same instance but I think that's OK since one of my local projects is the CommManager which deals with callback interface, and API is already shared with 3rd party

Here's what I have so far for the library manager:

```
namespace Mechanical_Interactions
{
    public sealed class ZoneManager
    {

        private static readonly ZoneManager instance = new ZoneManager();

        private ZoneManager()
        {
            //read in XML file into 2 Enumerable lists: users & content representing all locations and a list of all possible resources who could claim access to such a zone for avoiding collision and conflict prior to movement
        }

        public static ZoneManager getManager()
        {
            return instance;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Content>periodicals{get;}
        public IEnumerable<Users>users{get;}
        
        public bool requestAccess(string zone,string resource)
        {
            //mutex-locked, checks if zone is in-use by other resource, if so, return false. If not, apply resourceID as owner in zone object and return true
        }
        public void returnContent(string title, string resource)
        {
            //confirm the resource releasing access is the same who received in first place. if so, release access tag. failure is insignificant, as next requestOfAccess will return false and can be handled there
        }
        private object Mutex {get;} = new object();

    }

    public static class Zone
    {
        //string ID
        //string currentOwner
    }

    public class Resource
    {
        //string ID
        //List<Zone> InUseZones{get;} 
    }
}
```

Comment: A singleton is a single instance relative to a scope. The kind of singleton you have here is scoped to the type system, which exists per process (another kind of scope is a DI container). If you're expecting that single instance to be shared across all applications using the assembly you're referencing, that's not going to happen. You need some kind of single-instance EXE and an IPC mechanism to coordinate with the processes that need to use it. Where do your needs/expectations lie?

Comment: Jon Skeet has a wonderful article on singletons: https://csharpindepth.com/articles/singleton

Comment: @madreflection my intent is to be referenced only within a single executable, as well as across WCF by 3rd party executables via callback interface on the functions (requestAccess() returnContent()) exclusively. so I assume given that assumption, I'd be able to use as-is, and simply start the instance at my "base" level VB code: the project that is set as StartUp Project within the Solution ala "Dim Manager = new Mechanical_Interactions.ZoneManager.getManager()" so long as theres an "Import" and reference for the DLL. Is that right?

Comment: There's a lot to unpack in that, as more than one of those statements could be interpreted in multiple ways. Even *"only within a single executable"* could have been more than one meaning; "executable" could mean any process started from that executable or only allowing one such process, so it's unclear how the singleton really needs to be scoped.

Comment: It's important to be verbose and precise. It may be tiresome to do so, but the less you leave to interpretation, the better.